# How to access Block Layout data and add to render array for rendering in a Twig template?

Tags: theming, blocks

I'm a relatively new Drupal developer, and this ticket for my job has been proving extremely difficult for me to figure out through research.

I want to access the block layout data (/admin/structure/block/manage/block_name_example?destination=/admin/structure/block) for a custom block that we're using for our hero page banner. We're using the Block Scheduler plugin, which provides an Expiry tab to set the Publish and Expiry date for blocks. This banner usually contains a sale, and instead of adding a new field to the Block and setting the expiry date in two places, we're wanting to simply pull the date that we set in that Expiry tab.

Here's a visual representation of the field we want to access by passing the data to theme's render array for use within a designated Twig template for this block:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know what specific API or functionality I would even need to use to meet the requirements I've outlined above.